# Error in modelling a photovoltaic panel using Plecs software. What could be wrong?

Tags: circuit-design, solar-cell, solar-energy, modeling

[image]

I have a work titled MPPT P and O algorithm with a buck-boost converter.
The software I am to use is Plecs.

First I wanted to design a photovoltaic model in Plecs. I tried to follow an example I got in a textbook but there was an error that says:

> initialization commands of model'sun' cannot be evaluated :error:load:unable to find file PVLookupData_BP365_single.mat.

I would appreciate it if someone can help me to take a look at it.

Comment: Welcome!  You'll find you get the best out of EE.SE if you give good details of your situation.  For example, what's the textbook?  Seems it's trying to open a file called `PVLookupData_BP365_single.mat`.  (Insolation data for a single panel for a year, at a guess)  Do you have it?

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing something like [this](https://www.plexim.com/sites/default/files/plecs_pvstring.pdf).  I didn't do anything cleverer than searching, and it appears that there is such a file available in public git hub [here](https://github.com/satyajeetdeshmukh/Standalone-PV-Simulation/blob/main/Models/PVLookupData_BP365.mat).  The other files might also be useful to you.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I just check the git hub. Am I going to load the data to my work?

Comment: That github appears to be someone's BSc project, and contains a good write up PDF, and the various plecs files ... my suggestion is read the report and see what parts apply to what you're doing.  The .mat file is a matlab dataset  The whole thing looks like it will be very helpful to you.

Comment: Alright , thank you.

Comment: Your response helped me. I will go through all the files on the GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a file `PVLookupData_BP365_single.mat`, which is apparently the performance data of a particular panel, in Matlab format.  See also Plexim Application Note [Modeling a Photovoltaic
String using PLECS](https://www.plexim.com/sites/default/files/plecs_pvstring.pdf).

I suggest you read *Standalone PV system design and development*, by Satyajeet Deshmukh and Himanshu Verma, a bachelor's thesis. Indian Institute of Technology Indore, 2021.

Their Github repository is [here](https://github.com/satyajeetdeshmukh/Standalone-PV-Simulation) and they have all the files you will need.  Start by reading the report PDF in the toplevel.